# From the Central-Limit Theorem, what does a sum of IID random variables converge in distribution to?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

From [1], we have the well known Lindeberg–Levy Central-Limit Theorem:

> [Lindeberg–Levy Central-Limit Theorem]
> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a sequence of  independent and identically distributed  random variables with $E[X_i] = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty.$  Then, as $n$  approaches infinity, the random variable  $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)$    converges in distribution  to a  normal distribution  $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$:
> $$
> \sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n - \mu\right)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right) .$$

I am able to go through the proof of this found in [1] without issue.

What I am curious about is how to manipulate the equation
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n - \mu\right)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)  
$$
to determine, for example, what
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i  \ \xrightarrow{d}\ ? 
$$

Imitating Alecos Papadopoulos from [2], I write that "by abusing notation and asymptotics [2]", I have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  \ \approx\ 
\mathcal{N}\left(n\mu,
\left(\sqrt{n}
\sigma\right)^2
\right).
$$

Ok, I have a solution. Yet, I do not know if its correct; nor do I know how to obtain the result on my own. That's not where I would like to be.

**Question**

Can you show---without abusing notation or asymptotics---that  I can infer
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  \ \xrightarrow{d}\ 
\mathcal{N}\left(n\mu,
\left(\sqrt{n}
\sigma\right)^2
\right) 
$$
from
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n - \mu\right)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)  ?
$$

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#

[2] Alecos Papadopoulos (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/87400/alecos-papadopoulos), Why does the central limit theorem imply that the standard deviation approaches $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$?, URL (version: 2018-07-14): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515040

Comment: "Can you show---without abusing notation or asymptotics---that I can infer [...]" it is not clear what you mean because in the next line you proceed to abuse both notation and asymptotics

Comment: One way try to formalise this is to show that $\|F_n-G_n\|$ is small, where $F_n$ is the CDF of your sum and $G_n$ is the CDF of the Normal distribution you quote

Comment: @JoseAvilez But...is it actually "small?"  In what sense do we quantify the smallness--clearly, it need not itself converge to $0$.  If we compute its magnitude relative to $n$, then yes, it gets small, but that's what the CLT in its stated form effectively says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step back and look at the issue a bit more naively.  If $X$ has finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then for any positive integer $n$, the iid sample total $n\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ will have mean $n \mu$ and variance $n \sigma^2$, which is simply a consequence of the linearity of expectation and the existence of finite moments.

So as $n$ grows, is it actually reasonable to say that $\bar X$ converges in such a manner?  What does such a statement even mean when the moments tend to infinity as $n \to \infty$?

Let's look at a specific example.  We know, for instance, that when $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$ with rate parametrization, then the sample total is gamma distributed with shape $n$ and rate $\lambda$:
$$n \bar X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, \lambda)$$
and the mean is $n/\lambda$ and variance $n/\lambda^2$.  That's not converging to a normal distribution no matter how large $n$ gets; it has a distinct distribution.  Same thing with the binomial distribution as the sum of iid Bernoulli variables.

That said, the shapes of the distributions of such sums does, in some vague sense, "look" more normal as $n$ increases.  But what does that actually mean in the context of moments that continue to increase without bound?  The whole point of the CLT is that a suitable location-scale transformation of the sample total results in the desired convergence in distribution.  The way it is formulated is the formalization of that "intuition" that, for large $n$, these distributions begin to "look" more normal.  As such there is no need to write a statement like $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Normal}(n\mu, n\sigma^2).$$  We can certainly write $\approx$ or justify the use of a normal approximation, but the CLT as it is formulated is the basis for such statements.

Comment: heropup, in a nut shell, are you stating that I replace the arrow with an approximation symbol? Also, I edited the post and so to avoid confusion please edit your top portion or future readers will be confused.

Comment: @MichaelLevy Well...that's not really what I was getting at, but it's not wrong to use $\approx$.  The issue here is that convergence in distribution is a specific concept, and yes, you are abusing that concept by treating it like an algebraic equality, as my example hopefully illustrates.  But if we use something like $\approx$, that's somewhat less rigorous because it doesn't really say in what sense the approximation is true.